# Angular - keep track of element's height to show/hide a 'More' button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I have a result set, each result is displayed in a panel. 
Currently the `height` of the panel is `auto` and it depends upon the length of that particular result.

The user also has an option to `show/hide` some of the properties displayed in the result which would lead to change in the height of the panel again.

Sometimes the results are very long and so each result panel takes a lot of space making it difficult for the user to scroll through the set . What i intend to achieve is if the `height` of the panel becomes more than 300px, a 'More' button should appear which would show the full `height` when clicked.

How should i go about doing this?

P.S: these are the current ideas
1) create a `directive` which watches the `height` of the element and as it goes beyond `300px`, displays the more button.

I think this would be overkill for such a small task, and also my result set can contain about hundreds of results at a time, so having a `directiv`e for each of them does not seem like a good idea

2) try to do it without a directive, initially set a `max-height` as `300px` and `overflow hidden`, and on `click` of 'More' `button`, just set the height to auto.

This does not involve `directives`, but the issue is sometimes my panel can be less than `300px` (also when the user chooses to show only a few properties), in that case how would i know when to `hide` the 'More' button. 
(I guess i would need some type of checking for height)